# symfony: trying to create a patch. What should be my first step(s)?

Tags: symfony1, patch

i created this ticked some days ago.

http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/8922#preview

I'm interested in creating a patch (if possible). I dont have experience
debugging (just using var_dump). What should be my first step(s) ?

Javi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to create a patch? Do you want to fix your problem and publish the solution? If so than patches are usually created with a diff tool: http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html

About your problem: you extend sfGuardUser class and add slug to the child table. Why do you expect that it shows up in the parent? It's not how inheritance works.

Comment: OK, i replace in the schema the inheritance type from 'simple' to 'concrete' and now the 'slug' field is created in the child table. No patches needed now...Thanks!.